# MVC-3/jQuery: stop validating my checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have MVC-3 user control (html helper & aspx view engine). Some how when I submit the form jQuery un-obtrusive validation fires up & requires me to check all checkboxes. How do I prevent it?

Further Info:

1) There is no required attribute in my model.

2) I am using this check-box inside [telerik gridview](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-introduction.html)

```
    namespace Alpha.Views
    {
        public class AlphaCheckBoxControl : ViewUserControl<AlphaCheckBox> { 
    }

    public class AlphaCheckBox
    {
        public bool isChecked;
        public string name { get; set; }
        public MvcHtmlString labelText;
        public bool readOnly;
        public bool visible { get; set; }

        public IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            if (readOnly) dict.Add(@"readonly", "readonly");
            if (readOnly) dict.Add("disabled", "disabled");
            return dict;
        }
    }  
}


<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Alpha.Views.AlphaCheckBoxControl" 
        AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="AlphaCheckBox.ascx.cs" %>


<tr>
      <td>
          <%= Html.Label(Model.name)%>
      </td>
      <td>
           <%= Html.CheckBox(Model.name, Model.isChecked, Model.htmlAttributes())%>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: You appear to be binding the checkbox to the `name` property. Is the name property required?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, this is just `CheckBox` html helper not `CheckBoxFor` first parameter is just a name to display, does not come into picture while model binding, correct me If I am wrong, please.

Comment: Check the html, I suspect it renders `<input type="checkbox" name="name" ../> so validation will be applied to the name property

Comment: Please show the relevant ***rendered*** HTML markup as seen by the browser.