# Getting two states for MVC CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image]
I am stuck up in a pretty basic page while reading form collection on post.
When I check the IsChecked checkbox, in the post action. I am getting `"true, false"` in the FormCollection. My goal is to obtain the string in below code and then parse it to boolean.

I have not idea where is the bug, can you please help?

[image]

Post Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        var checkedd = collection["IsChecked"].ToString();
        var name = collection["Name"].ToString();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsChecked) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsChecked) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsChecked) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name) %>
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

Comment: How about having that method take `Product` as parameter instead of `FormCollection` and have your page bound to the model?

Comment: @shahkalpesh, Model binding is what I use in recent applications, I had been working on old code, where I faced this issue. This sample application was just to learn how `FormCollection` works :-)

Comment: Going to old way of doing things, does `Request["IsChecked"]` help? I don't know the exact syntax. This is the classic asp way to extract form post values.

Comment: @shahkalpesh `Request["IsChecked"]` also returns "true,false"

Comment: In that case, something is wrong with your form. Do a view source on it to see if there is more than 1 element with name IsChecked? I suppose that could be the reason. Check the content being posted using IE dev toolbar, network tab, start capturing (before you click Submit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you passing a model to you view, why are you using `FormCollection`? if you change you POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product model)
{
```

you model will be correctly bound.

The reason you are getting this value for the `IsChecked` is that the `CheckBoxFor` helper renders 2 controls - `<input type="checkbox" ..>` and `<input type="hidden" ...>`.

> Because unchecked checkboxes do not post back, the 2nd hidden input
>   ensures a value of false is posted back when its unchecked. The
>   default model binder reads the first value matching the property name
>   and (ignores the second if it exists).

If you really want to use `FormCollection`, then don't use `CheckBoxFor` - just manually include the html for a checkbox. Then if the value exists in `FormCollection`, it must be `true`, otherwise it must be false

Comment: Wow, two input elements: Two input elements: jQuery un-obtrusive validation has been stopping me to submit inline-edit to a grid, if unless I check all check-boxes on the grid.

Comment: Stephen Could you help me on this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831229/mvc-3-jquery-stop-validating-my-checkbox

Comment: Sure, but give me half an hour - can you post the html in that question as per comments

Comment: @Abhijeet, Note that one of the elements is a checkbox but the other is a hidden input (not a checkbox) - its just there to ensure a value is posted back